# Linux with multiples VLAN is partialy reachable

Tags: linux, networking, routes, trunk

my network is made of several VLANs. I already have a router doing its job routing packets from one Vlan to another.
The problem occurs on a Linux server with 1 single interface, for which i expected to allow severals IP from several Vlan.

In order to be more specific: the Linux server has eth0.1, eth0.2, eth0.3 virtual interfaces connected to a frunk interface from switch. Each virtual interface has its own IP from each VLans.

wenn i try to reach the Linux-eth0.2 IP from a computer from VLAN 2 that s Works
wenn i try to reach the Linux-eth0.1 IP from a computer from VLAN 1 that s Works
and from the server i m able to reach each single VLANs (without going through the router).

but my problem occurs wenn a computer from VLAN 2 try to reach my server IP from VLAN 1 (eth0.1)

This problem could be solved creating static route on client side, but does exist a way from the server side to ensure this comunication Works.

I do not expect to have my Linux server acting as a router, only answering request comming to any of it s interface
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us the networks on each vlan configured on the server that has the do1q subinterfaces and the networks configured on the router.
From what i understand you want to get to the server via the default route(passing through the router if you jump vlans) ,or get to the server directly if you work in the same vlan .
in order to do this you need to have the interfaces on the server from the same subnet as the pc's .
simply put:

ROUTER ///////////////////////////////////////////////// SERVER

INTERFACE VLAN 1 - 192.168.0.1/24    ETH0.1 - 192.168.0.2/24

INTERFACE VLAN 2 - 192.168.1.1/24    ETH0.2 - 192.168.1.2/24

INTERFACE VLAN 3 - 192.168.2.1/24    ETH0.3 - 192.168.2.2/24

Hope it helps.